# left-censored dependent variables and prediction

Tags: monte-carlo, data-imputation, prediction-interval, censoring, tobit-regression

I'm coding up a monte-carlo analysis; I've got a deterministic model that depends on parameters that are uncertain.  One of those uncertain parameters is a partially-observed vector of prices by country -- I want to predict missing values in a manner similar to what is used in multiple imputation via chained equations.

I've got a few candidates for modeling those missing values:

1. A linear model with censored predictions -- I simply censor negative predictions at zero.  Average predictions will probably be biased upwards because of the left-censoring.
2. A linear model fit to a log-transformed price.  Average predictions will be biased upwards because of the unnaturally fat right tail, and the probability of responses at the right tail will be unnaturally fat.
3. A glm with gaussian errors and a logarithmic link.  I don't really have the intuition for this, but examining a few predictions gives me results that are even crazier than for #2.
4. A tobit model.  This is the best choice, but how does one even think of a prediction interval in that case?  How does one code it?

Edit:  when I say "prediction" I'm talking about a random draw from the fitted model's predictive distribution.